# Vagrantfile with docker provider portfoward error

Tags: mysql, docker, vagrant, vagrant-provision

I want to set up an environment with Vagrant. I defined 2 mysql in Vagrantfile, one for development, and one for integration tests. To differentiate these 2 instance I want to expose different ports.

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
 config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.100.138", nic_type: "82545EM"

 config.vm.define "mysql" do |m|
   config.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
     d.name = "mysql"
     d.image = "mysql:8"
     d.ports = ["3306:3306"]    
     d.env = {"MYSQL_DATABASE" => "development", "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" => "root"}
     d.remains_running = true
   end
 end

 config.vm.define "mysql-integration-test" do |mit|
   config.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
     d.name = "mysql-integration-test"
     d.image = "mysql:8"
     d.ports = ["3406:3306"]    
     d.env = {"MYSQL_DATABASE" => "development-it", "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" => "root"}
     d.remains_running = true
   end
 end
end
```

The problem is when I started it I got an error than the port is already in use:

```
jmecsei@jmecsei:~/Work/vagrant$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'mysql' up with 'docker' provider...
Bringing machine 'mysql-integration-test' up with 'docker' provider...
==> mysql: Creating and configuring docker networks...
==> mysql-integration-test: Creating and configuring docker networks...
==> mysql: Creating the container...
    mysql:   Name: mysql-integration-test
    mysql:  Image: mysql:8
    mysql: Volume: /home/jmecsei/Work/vagrant:/vagrant
    mysql:   Port: 3406:3306
    mysql:  
    mysql: Container created: 94c0f18c6938365f
==> mysql-integration-test: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2200.
==> mysql-integration-test: An error occurred. The error will be shown after all tasks complete.
==> mysql: Enabling network interfaces...
==> mysql: Starting container...
An error occurred while executing multiple actions in parallel.
Any errors that occurred are shown below.

An error occurred while executing the action on the 'mysql-integration-test'
machine. Please handle this error then try again:

Vagrant cannot forward the specified ports on this VM, since they
would collide with some other application that is already listening
on these ports. The forwarded port to 3406 is already in use
on the host machine.

To fix this, modify your current project's Vagrantfile to use another
port. Example, where '1234' would be replaced by a unique host port:

  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3306, host: 1234

Sometimes, Vagrant will attempt to auto-correct this for you. In this
case, Vagrant was unable to. This is usually because the guest machine
is in a state which doesn't allow modifying port forwarding. You could
try 'vagrant reload' (equivalent of running a halt followed by an up)
so vagrant can attempt to auto-correct this upon booting. Be warned
that any unsaved work might be lost.
```

Comment: Did you get to resolve this? I'm having a very similar issue.

Comment: Unfortunatelly no. Finally we drop the Vagrant and use docker instead.